# How include contributions to a manuscript of a paper in CV

Tags: publications, cv

I'm an undergraduate submitting my Resume for a variety of internships and need advice about how (if?) I should include my contributions to a manuscript that my group intends to publish. This would be my first publication so I leave it off I feel that I would really be cutting myself short. I mention my position and the work I did, but I feel it won't carry nearly as much weight if I don't mention that it was in support of a paper.

Comment: Are you going to be a co-author on the paper, when it is published?

Comment: @ff524 as far as I know. I have written a section for the paper (as has a grad student) and my PI has said that we will be coauthors of the final publication.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a student, it is entirely appropriate for you to list manuscripts "in progress." However, I would make sure that the manuscript is actually progressing before listing it on your CV.

If it's in preparation, you then list it as you would any other publication, except where it's published (journal, volume, page, year), you instead list where you plan to submit it (if you know that):

> Author List (including you). Title of manuscript. To be submitted to *Journal X*.

or, if you don't know where it's going to be submitted:

> Author List. Title of Manuscript. In preparation.

Comment: I would write with (in preparation) instead of where the year would go. I would not put intended journal of publication, that is a bit presumptuous to me.

Comment: @Behacad: If you already know where it's going to be submitted, you can certainly write "To be submitted to _Journal X_."

Comment: Yes this is true, but I would not put that it is the "intended journal of publication" as written in your answer.

Comment: OK. The new version is clearer, I think.